# Can't hide SharePoint Date fields with jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, date, hide, field

This works on regular input fields, but can't seem to make it work on date field which seems to generate a date picker and javascript.

```
$('input[title=Followup Date]').parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

How can I do this? My generated markup looks like this

```
<TR>
        <TD nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Followup Date</nobr>
    </H3></TD>
        <TD valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px">
        <!-- FieldName="Followup Date"
             FieldInternalName="Followup_x0020_Date"
             FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
          -->
            <span dir="none">
        <SCRIPT language='javascript'>g_strDateTimeControlIDs["SPFollowup_x0020_Date"] = "ctl00_m_g_4175fece_4419_4c1f_a18a_4357d8c9376e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl08_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate";</SCRIPT>
                        <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>
                        <td class="ms-dtinput" >
                        <label for="ctl00_m_g_4175fece_4419_4c1f_a18a_4357d8c9376e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl08_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate" style="display:none">Followup Date Date</label>
                        <input name="ctl00$m$g_4175fece_4419_4c1f_a18a_4357d8c9376e$ctl00$ctl04$ctl08$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDate" type="text" maxlength="45" id="ctl00_m_g_4175fece_4419_4c1f_a18a_4357d8c9376e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl08_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate" title="Followup Date" class="ms-input" AutoPostBack="0" /></td>
                        <td class="ms-dtinput" >
                        <A href="#" onclick='clickDatePicker("ctl00_m_g_4175fece_4419_4c1f_a18a_4357d8c9376e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl08_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate", "\u002fsites\u002fforms\u002fBrightIdeas\u002f_layouts\u002fiframe.aspx?&cal=1&lcid=1033&langid=1033&tz=-04:00:00.0001681&ww=0111110&fdow=0&fwoy=0&hj=0&swn=False&minjday=109207&maxjday=2666269&date=", ""); return false;' ><IMG id=ctl00_m_g_4175fece_4419_4c1f_a18a_4357d8c9376e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl08_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage src="/_layouts/images/calendar.gif" border="0" alt="Select a date from the calendar."></IMG></A></td>
```

Comment: You're missing the double quotes on the title name (or was that just a typo on the question?) have you tried this?
$('input[title="Followup Date"]').parent().parent().parent().hide();

Comment: That helped thanks.. but I had to add a few more .parent() to get the entire line (label and all) hidden. $('input[title="Followup Date"]').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();